# Flutter ADB error: ADB exited with exit code 1 performing streamed install

Tags: android, flutter, adb

Launching lib\main.dart on SM G955F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
error: closed
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: connect error for write: closed
Error launching application on SM G955F.

This is just the default stuff. I haven't changed anything